# How can i reset UIlabel attributes to default settings in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I created a `UIlabel` named **etiket**. then I created an action button and I made changes like color change on it. it's a sample:

```
@IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: Any) {
    etiket.textColor = UIColor.red
```

then I created again an action button and now when I pressed the button I want to reset `UIlabel` to default settings.

I tried this method

```
@IBAction func sifirla(_ sender: Any) {
    etiket.text = "nil"
```

when I tried this method `UIlabel` completely disappeared.

How can I reset `UIlabel` attributes to default settings?
I did some research, but I could not find exactly what I wanted.

Comment: your question is not clear..please provide more clarity......what do you mean by default settings?

Comment: this is default label "https://i.stack.imgur.com/LccBY.png" and this is red label(not whiskey:) https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Bco.png

Comment: You can try to reset your label by setting a new instance of UILabel.
@IBAction func sifirla(_ sender: Any) {
    etiket = UILabel()
}

Comment: @IBAction func sifirla(_ sender: Any) { etiket = UILabel() } not working

Comment: check edit...you will get an idea..:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a label dynamically and assign a tag value to it.

```
func createLabel() -> UILabel {
    let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 55))
    lbl.tag = 101
    //set other properties of label
    return lbl
}
```

In `changeColor` method you need to get label by tag value and set its color.

```
@IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: Any) {

    if let lbl = self.view.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel {
        lbl.textColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

In `sifirla` method you need to get label by tag value and remove it from its super view and create a new label and add it in your current view, so by adding a new UILabel instance you will get default settings of label.

```
@IBAction func sifirla(_ sender: Any) {

    if let lbl = self.view.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel {
        lbl.removeFromSuperview()

        let newLbl = self.createLabel()
        self.view.addSubview(newLbl)
    }
}
```

Note: If you are using autolayout then you need to set constraint to label instead of frame.